# Prove that functional series $\sum_{n=1}|\sin x|^{\sqrt{n}}$ is convergent when $x \in (-1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Prove that functional series $\sum_{n=1}|\sin x|^{\sqrt{n}}$ is convergent when $x \in (-1,1)$.

I do not know if that's so easy that I'm simply missing something, but I can't find any criterion which would solve this.

Comment: Can you prove, for instance, that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}$ is convergent?

Comment: I was thinking about that, but couldn't do it.

Comment: Have you tried comparisons with known convergent series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\vert\sin x\vert \le \vert x\vert$ and to conclude it suffices to prove that the series $\sum \vert x\vert^{\sqrt n}$ is convergent. We have
$$n^2 \vert x\vert^{\sqrt n}=\exp(\sqrt n\ln\vert x\vert+2\ln n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
so we have $\vert x\vert^{\sqrt n}\le \frac1{n^2}$ for $n$ large enough and the result follows by comparison with a Riemann convergent series.

Answer (score 1):

Since $-1<x<1$, you have $|\sin x|<1$. Then $\log|\sin x|<0$. We have
$$
|\sin x|^{\sqrt n}=e^{\sqrt n\,\log|\sin x|}.
$$
If we now compare with the integral,
$$
\int_1^\infty e^{t\,\log|\sin x|}\,dt=\left.\frac{e^{t\,\log|\sin x|}}{\log|\sin x|}\right|_1^\infty=-\frac{e^{\log|\sin x|}}{\log|\sin x|}<\infty.
$$
So the series converges.

Comment: Thanks, but I should be able to do it without integrals.

Comment: You didn't say that in the question.

Comment: It would be hard to forsee any solution which works and I am not able to understand it now. Currently I know only some very basic points about integrals.

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk the intuition behind integral test is very straightforward and easy to follow, so is its proof. You can just google it and work it out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(1)<0.9$ and $\sum\limits_{k=n^2+1}^{(n+1)^2} a^\sqrt{k}<(2n+1)a^n$.

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (\sin x)^\sqrt{k}\le \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (\sin 1)^\sqrt{k}< \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty 0.9^\sqrt{k}\le \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (2k+1)0.9^k= 2\frac{0.9}{(1-0.9)^2}+\frac{0.9}{1-0.9}=189$